# Edit specific nodes in WP_Admin_Bar

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, admin-bar

Is it **easily possible** to edit links in the `WP_Admin_Bar` global `$wp_admin_bar` instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes** I recently ran into the situation where I wanted to change the profile link in the user-info section of the admin bar. The problem is that you can only get all nodes, add and remove them. Not edit. And you also cannot modify the `$wp_admin_bar->nodes` property due it is private.

When easily removing and adding them, you'll lose your order and the whole thing looks horrible. Now here is my solution:

```
// void jw_edit_admin_bar ( mixed $id , string $property , string $value )

if(!function_exists('jw_edit_admin_bar')) {
    function jw_edit_admin_bar($id, $property, $value) {
        global $wp_admin_bar;

        if(!is_array($id)) {
            $id = array($id);
        }

        $all_nodes = $wp_admin_bar->get_nodes();

        foreach($all_nodes as $key => $val) {
            $current_node = $all_nodes[$key];
            $wp_admin_bar->remove_node($key);

            if(in_array($key, $id)) {
                $current_node->$property = $value;
            }

            $wp_admin_bar->add_node($current_node);
        }
    }
}

add_action('admin_bar_menu', function() { jw_edit_admin_bar(array('user-info', 'my-account'), 'href', 'http://www.nyan.cat'); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I recently ran into an issue trying to create a custom Holiday/Time of Day Greeting for the Wordpress Admin Toolbar and ran across this answer, which led me down a path of hours of wasted time since it is actually completely unnecessary. You don't need to destroy and rebuild the admin toolbar to edit a node.

The simple solution for Julien's issue is a 5 line addition to your functions.php file that replaces the desired url:

```
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* change location of user profile page in admin toolbar */
add_filter( 'edit_profile_url', 'update_admin_bar_user_profile_url', 10, 3 );
function update_admin_bar_user_profile_url( $url, $user_id, $scheme ) {
    $url = site_url( '/edit-user-profile/' );
    return $url;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now if you want to get a bit deeper into editing/manipulating the the Admin Toolbar - you can do something like this, which adds the website url of the user, if they entered one in their profile page, as a node to the Users Profile Panel (aka a link in the "sub-menu"):

```
    /* --- add the user website link node in the admin toolbar --- */
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'update_admin_bar_user_node', 250 );
function update_admin_bar_user_node( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $profile_url = get_edit_profile_url( $user_id );

    if ( ! $user_id )
            return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'read' ) ) {
        $profile_url = get_edit_profile_url( $user_id );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        $profile_url = get_dashboard_url( $user_id, 'profile.php' );
    } else {
        $profile_url = false;
    }

    // Add the users website/link to the user-actions sub-menu if they have one 
    $my_account = $wp_admin_bar->get_node( 'my-account' );
    if( ! empty( $current_user->user_url ) && $my_account ){
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
            'parent'    => 'user-actions',
            'id'        => 'user-url',
            'title'     => '<span class="user-url">' . __( 'My Website' ) . '</span>',
            'href'      => esc_url( $current_user->user_url )
        ) );
    }       
}
```

Here is a screenshot of how that change looks in the "my-account" "user-actions" menu:
[image]

Comment: That looks interesting. Do you know if this hook was added after I originally posted? WP dev often feels like a rabbit hole IMHO. They have thought of almost everything and it's hard from time to time to find the best approach. Also I often feel like there *must* be a hook or filter (this thread is a good example) and it takes forever to find, if you're lucky at all ;)

Comment: I agree, it is extremely difficult at times to find what you are looking for in their resources. That said, I think when I started I searched for wp_admin_bar and found some references. Something else that I wanted to post here was a complete list of default nodes and their priorities (positions) within the toolbar. If you notice, the priority I set for this change was 250 - which was based on that list.

Comment: Sorry, I hate how Stack controls its posting, I frequently have to edit to make things look legible - especially for new folks like myself.

Comment: I omitted the part of the code that dealt with replacing "Howdy" with the Time of Day Greeting because I thought it might be viewed as being beyond the scope of the question, but that hooks into the node "my-account" and can be replaced by a sprintf assignment using the following node method/array...

'  $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array( 
   'id'  => 'my-account',
   'parent' => 'top-secondary',
   'title'  => $newtitle . $avatar,
   'href'  => $profile_url,
   'meta'  => array(
    'class'  => $class,
   ),
  ) );
'

Comment: The variables used in that method call are:
$avatar = get_avatar( $user_id, 26);
$greeting = tod_greeting_text();
$newtitle = sprintf( __( '%1$s, %2$s' ), $greeting, '<span class="display-name">' . $current_user->display_name . '</span>' );
$class    = empty( $avatar ) ? '' : 'with-avatar';
...of course tod_greeting_text() is a function call to a routine to parse and return the greeting message text string.

Comment: Oh, and I cannot find that list of priorities again :-(