# Hook into 'admin_url' but only on Mysites admin bar menu

Tags: multisite, admin, admin-bar

I'd like to alter admin url only inside "My Sites" admin bar menu..

[image]

I tried this filter:

```
add_filter( 'admin_url', function( $url, $path, $blog_id ){ return $url . "str" });
```

but when I do that it messes up every post edit post link?

Is there a way I can edit admin url only to that scoped section?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Instead of using the `admin_url` filter, have you tried using the `admin_bar_menu` action hook? It allows you to modify to rewrite the items inside the admin toolbar: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96869/edit-specific-nodes-in-wp-admin-bar

Comment: thanks for helo @terresquall but I can't hook into `$wp_admin_bar->get_node('my-sites')` instance there ... to be able to manipulate items?